# How can i pass parameters on redirection using react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react router version 2.0.1 for navigation between components. I came across a scenario where i want dynamically navigate to other component
I did something like this for redirection

```
browserHistory.push("/some/path");
```

It is navigating to other component perfectly. But i also want to pass some parameters along with the redirection.
I tried doing it like

```
browserHistory.push("/some/path", {query: "param1"});
browserHistory.push("/some/path", {query: {param1: value1}});
```

But when i try to fetch the value from `this.props.location` it shows blank query result.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `.push({ pathname: "/..", query: { "param" } })` https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#programmatic-navigation

Comment: @azium no it didn't work :(

Comment: any asnwer for this?

Answer (score 4):

This shuld work for you:

```
router.push({
  pathname: '/some/path',
  query: { param1: value1 } 
})
```

or I've seen people doing this and looks like its workin ok:

```
browserHistory.push("/some/path?param1=value1");
```